# Xubuntu 17.10 Nautilus doesn't open files

Tags: xubuntu, nautilus

I loaded Nautilus in Xubuntu 17.10 because I like to see the sync emblems with Dropbox. I changed the file manager in Preferred Applications to Nautilus.

When in Nautilus, when I search and find a file, say a text file, and either double click or hit enter, instead of opening the text file in a text editor, it opens another Nautilus window.

This doesn't happen in Thunar.

Switching back to Thunar has the expected behavior of opening a file when I hit enter.

Any ideas on how to make Nautilus open files on enter?

Comment: Dropbox works fine without Nautilus.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the issue. Syncing is fine, I just can't see the status of a sync without looking in Nautilus to see if there's a green checkmark on the folder. That part works. What is not working is pressing enter or double clicking a file in Nautilus opens a new Nautilus window and not the associated app for the file (like a text editor for a .txt file).

Comment: That is to be expected since Nautilus isn't the default file manager, Thunar is.

Comment: But I've changed my default file manager to Nautilus and it still won't open files when I hit enter. I can easily reproduce the problem - if I DON'T set Nautilus as the default file manager in Preferred Applications(that is, leave Thunar as default), it works as expected. When I make Nautilus/Files the default file manager, it does not allow opening of files with enter. What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I fixed it by editing this configuration file:

**~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list**

I had this line

```
x-scheme-handler/file=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
```

I just commented it out and files now open as expected.

Comment: I don't have a mimeapps.list in that directory. Any other ideas? I also looked at nemo and it seems pretty good. Only problem is I can't add the Dropbox support in Xubuntu 17.10. Any ideas on how to add it?

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, looks like a bug with Ubuntu Nautilus build. Installed Debian Sid Nautilus over and now it works again:

- [Debian -- Details of package nautilus in sid](https://packages.debian.org/sid/nautilus)
- [Debian -- Details of package libnautilus-extension1a in sid](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libnautilus-extension1a)
- [Debian -- Details of package nautilus-data in sid](https://packages.debian.org/sid/nautilus-data)

Answer (score 0):

I wound up loading Nemo 2.8.7 from here. I'd rather Thunar had Dropbox folder emblems, but this will have to do.

[Latest Nemo File Manager With Extensions & Patches For Ubuntu Via Dedicated PPA](http://www.noobslab.com/2017/01/latest-nemo-file-manager-with.html)